# Scrolling the terminal without a mouse

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

I'm sure this has been asked before, but anytime I try scrolling using the arrow, page up/down keys and/or those in combination with ctrl, shift, alt, etc. It just types some odd combination of symbols into the terminal. Something like `` {`3| ``, though I don't remember exactly.

For example, this makes it impossible to see for example anything above the letter S when I check for all installed applications.

I am very new to Linux and I only know some of the basics and am trying to learn it. I've googled but nothing really helped me there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it may vary depending on the terminal software, but try CTRL + SHIFT + up arrow. You can also shift and use page up/down.

Comment: I've done a bit more testing. I could probably turn this into an answer, or someone else can do some more testing and let you know. The SHIFT + Page Up/Down seems to be pretty universal. The SHIFT + Up/Down arrow is less universal. For example, it doesn't work in Terminator. The SHIFT and arrow keys work in QTerminal and XFCE's terminal.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. Either of those cobos don't work for me. I will try HuHa's answer though and see if that does it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KGIII that works for me on multiple terminals I use daily. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a mouse available, better pipe that command output to `less` (the more modern version of `more`):

```
dpkg -i | less
```

This is *made* for keyboard use, unlike those graphical terminals' scroll bars.

See `man less` for all the key combinations. Most important: Space bar (next), PgUp, PgDn, Home, End.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. I will try it tomorrow and get back to you!